How do I find a minimum/maximum of f(x) to sketch graph of a polynomial?
I have been studying precalculus and I am currently on graphing of polynomials greater than degree 2. I am at a point where the textbook involves summary exercises for various parts of the chapter but I seem to be at a loss as to how to the question above.
For example, I am asked to graph $f(x) = 3x^4 - 14x^2 - 5$.
I know how to get the answer for the sequence of sub-exercises for this particular question, which are, in general:
a) Use the rational zeroes theorem to find possibilities for such.
b) Find all other real zeroes.
c) Find the x-intercepts (basically the zeroes) and the y-intercept (which would simply be setting x to zero and finding y.
d) Finding whether the graph is below or above whatever test point is used in the intervals between zeroes of the graph.
The end result is a graph as shown in the pic. It doesn't show it but the y-intercept is - 5.
I don't expect anyone here to actually solve for the y-minimum, which is about - 21.32, according to my calculator.
As I am supposed to sketch this and not use a calculator, if anyone can at least point me in the right direction with the name of the process to find the minimum of the polynomial so that I may look it up myself and learn how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated.
Is there a named process by I could learn how to do what my question asks?


For the zeros of $f$: Set $z = x^2$. Then you have to solve $3z^2-14z-5=0$. Let's say, one of your results is $z=4$. Then $x^2 = 4$ yields $x=\pm 2$.

I've given the most involved answer I could muster!

Drawing higher degree polynomials in a very accurate way can be quite tough. Let me address your specific polynomial and how I would expect students who I teach (mostly grades 10-12) to approach it:
The polynomial is $f(x) =  3x^4 - 14x^2 - 5$.
Depending on where in the year this problem appears, one might know:
a) This is an even polynomial, meaning, all of the exponents are even numbers (you can even imagine the constant term being written as $-5x^0$ if you want to push this idea through). As a result, $f(-x) = f(x)$, which means that the graph will have a line of reflection along the y-axis, $x=0$.
b) The leading coefficient is positive and the degree (the highest exponent on a variable) is even – in particular, the leading coefficient is $3$ and the degree is $4$ – so we know from end behavior that the function's graph is going upwards to $+\infty$ on both sides i.e. as $x$ goes far to the right and as $x$ goes far to the left, eventually the $y$ values go upwards.
c) You can make the substitution $t = x^2$ to rewrite this polynomial as quadratic in $t$: In particular, you would end up with $3t^2 - 14t - 5$, and now you can use your techniques of factoring to rewrite this polynomial and then sub back in $t = x^2$. Here ,we get:
$$3t^2 - 14t - 5 = (3t + 1)(t - 5) = (3x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 5)$$
Now we know there are two $x$-intercepts: By looking at the $x^2 - 5$ factor, we have $x = \pm \sqrt5 \approx 2.24$.
d) Like always, the constant term gives us the $y$-intercept. In particular, you can find the $y$-intercept by plugging in $x=0$, which will leave only the $-5$ at the end. So your function has $y$-intercept $(0,-5)$.
At this point, we have enough pieces to put together an okay sketch of the graph:
Draw the $x$-intercepts at about $2.24$ (which is about $2\frac{1}{4}$) and the $y$-intercept at $-5$. Personally, I might check a point where $x$ is somewhere in the region between the graphed point, like, $0<x<\sqrt{5}$. The easiest number I can think of is $1$, and we can just calculate: $f(1) = 3-14-5 = -16$. So, okay, the function goes down a bit from the $y$-intercept and then loops back up through the $x$-intercept at $(\sqrt{5}, 0)$ and keeps going. Once you have drawn this on the right hand side of the graph, we saw in a) above that the left hand side of the graph should be a mirrored reflection over the $y$-axis.
As to the breakdown you included, we managed to find all zeros: $x = \pm \sqrt{5}$. If we use the zero product property to investigate the other factors when $3x^2 + 1 = 0$, we get that $x$ is not a real number. There's no need to use the Rational Root Theorem – we know from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that there are four complex roots, and we found two of them here (irrational) and see the other two are complex (not real) – which means that even if you used the RRT on all candidates, none would show up.
Finding minimum:
Looking back to our $t = x^2$ substitution, observe that
$$3t^2 - 14t - 5 = 3\big(t - \frac{7}{3}\big)^2 - \frac{64}{3} = 3\big(x^2 - \frac{7}{3}\big)^2 - \frac{64}{3}$$
This final factorization of your given polynomial has it in the form:
$$\text{(positive number)} \cdot \text{something}^2 + k$$
Since the leading coefficient is positive, this function has a minimum; since it can be rewritten in the form above, we see this minimum occurs when the first part is zero, i.e., when $x^2 = 7/3$, and that the global minimums will occur at these points: evaluating your function here will give e.g.
$$f\Big(\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}\Big) = 3(0)^2 - \frac{64}{3} = -\frac{64}{3}$$
This finds your global minimum of $-64/3 = -21.333\ldots$ as desired.
If you were not sure how to rewrite the function as above, this is essentially completing the square; it takes a quadratic function written in standard form as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and rewrites it in vertex form as $a(x-h)^2 + k$ where $h=-\frac{b}{2a}$ and $k = f(h)$. Once we did this with the quadratic polynomial in $t$, we could substitute back in our original value of $x^2$. In this way, we find not only the minimum of $-21.333\ldots$, but also that it occurs at $x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}$.
You can find this graphed in Desmos here.

As I understand your answer, it would be exceedingly difficult for me to give a definitive answer to the minimum which is appx. -21.32 (per the calculator) using the processes of the precalculus course I am taking. Perhaps, in later calculus, I would be able to find the answer by manual calculation, but as I see it, based on your comment, sketching a ballpark estimate near -21.32 (in your answer it would be f(1)=-16) would suffice as it has the general shape of the pic I've given and is close enough to -21.32 (the calculator minimum), which is a reasonable assumption, I think.

@DavidA. I've edited in how the minimum can be found for your particular $f(x)$ quartic polynomial!
